# H2 equivalent of Postgres `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL` column?

Tags: primary-key, h2, auto-increment

In [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/), defining a column with [`SERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)/[`BIGSERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) has a triple effect as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389891/642706):

- Define a `int`/`bigint` column.
- Create a sequence object to generate auto-incrementing numbers.
- Set the default of the column to call `nextval()` on the sequence.

Is there a similar shortcut command in [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) to get this related set of behavior?

If not, what would the long version of the SQL be?

Comment: IDENTITY is the auto-increment equivalent, as H2 docs would tell you

Comment: @NeilStockton Where does the sequence live? How can you adjust its value or reset it? The doc for `IDENTITY` type does not say much. In Postgres, the sequence is a separate object in the database, owned by the column.

Comment: This is NOT a SEQUENCE, which H2 also supports. AUTOINCREMENT in MySQL is the same as IDENTITY ... it increments that column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Where does the sequence live? How can you adjust its value or reset it?*

If you create a column as `auto_increment` (or `identity`) H2 creates a sequence in the background. The name of that sequence can be obtained by looking at `information_schema.columns`:

```
create table foo 
(
  id           integer auto_increment,
  other_column varchar(20)
);
```

If you then run:

```
select column_name, column_default
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'FOO'
and table_schema = 'PUBLIC';
```

You'll get something like this:

```
COLUMN_NAME  | COLUMN_DEFAULT                                                              
-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID           | (NEXT VALUE FOR PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_C1C36118_ED1C_44D6_B573_6C00C5923EAC)
OTHER_COLUMN |
```

You can alter that sequence without problems:

```
alter sequence SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_C1C36118_ED1C_44D6_B573_6C00C5923EAC 
   restart with 42;
```

This is essentially identical to Postgres' serial data type

> *If not, what would the long version of the SQL be?*

```
create sequence foo_id_seq;

create table foo 
(
  id           integer default foo_id_seq.nextval,
  other_column varchar(20)
);
```

The big difference between this and a Postgres `serial` is that H2 does not know that the sequence "belongs" to the column. You need to drop it manually when the table is dropped.

`foo_id_seq.nextval` will actually be converted to `(NEXT VALUE FOR PUBLIC.FOO_ID_SEQ)` when the table is created (and it will be stored like that in `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: The system generated Sequence works fine with Hibernate. But a custom Sequence generated like "foo_id_seq.nextval" fails to works.
I check information_schema.columns and found that there's a column called IS_GENERATED which is true for system generated Sequence but false for custom Sequence. Any idea how to set it to true for custom Sequences?