# Postgres Bigserial Datatype

Tags: java, postgresql, bigint

I am trying to create Postgres table with Bigserial data type as a promary key. Once I am creating the table the table definition is getting changed to `bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('transactions.transaction_id_seq'::regclass),` to this. Please let me know why this happenning?

Thanks In Advance,
Somnath

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does Postgresql SERIAL work differently?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18389537/1995738)

Answer (score 9):

As noted in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), serials are not "real" data types, but rather convenience wrappers. If you create a serial column, you automatically get

- a new sequence ('tablename_columnname_seq`)
- an integer column of the appropriate type that takes its default value from the sequence.
- the setup for the column to use the sequence.

To quote:

> The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases).

```
CREATE TABLE table (BIGSERIAL id PRIMARY KEY);
```

is the same as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE table (
   id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_id_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE table_id_seq OWNED BY table.id;
```

Which matches what you are getting.