# Postgres complains id 'already exists' after insert of initial data?

Tags: postgresql

I have an issue where Postgres is complaining of a duplicate ID following an import of some initial data and I am trying to see how to increment the id column counter?

Details:

I have recently uploaded some initial data into a Postgres table, where the id is set to autoincrement in my Sequelize model definition. For example:

```
    sequelize.define('user', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: Sequelize.STRING
    }
```

The data insert looks like:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("id","name") VALUES(1, "bob");
INSERT INTO "users" ("id","name") VALUES(2, "brooke");
INSERT INTO "users" ("id","name") VALUES(3, "nico");
```

Now from my node.js application when I try to insert a new record it complains that `Key (id)=(1) already exists`. The SQL Sequelize is using is of the form:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("id","name") VALUES(DEFAULT, "nico");
```

If I am empty the table of records and try this again or retry the operations enough times, then I see the counter does increment. The issue seems Postgres is not able to tell what the current max id is, based on the records?

What would be the right way to tell Postgres to update the counters, following uploading initial data into the database?

BTW using Postgres 9.6

Comment: [Does Postgresql SERIAL work differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389891/1995738)

Comment: See also [Serial Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

Comment: Behaviour described in linked article matches what we see here. That is manually specifying the id value won't update the sequence. Only  `DEFAULT` increments the value, so it appears important to refresh the sequence. This is different to MySQL, for example,  which increments automatically based on the largest value in the column.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After a bit more searching it turns out this will do what I need to do.

```
SELECT setval('users_id_seq', max(id)) FROM users;
```

This code will set the `id` to the current maximum id in the table, here it being my `users` table. Note, to check if a sequence is associated with a column, this will work:

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('patients', 'id')
```

The only thing to note is that you ignore the 'public.' part in the returned value.

I'll add the `setval()` to my initial data script.

Comment: I get "`users_id_seq` does not exist"

Comment: @étale-cohomology, I assume my response is probably quite late =) However, please note that: **users_id_seq** where `users` is a table name, `id` column in that table. You might have different name for your table and column.

Comment: Is it possible to set all tables and all primiary keys at once?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I inserted records using literal, numeric values (instead of DEFAULT or undefined) as arguments for the auto-incremented column. Doing so circumvents the column's [underlying sequence object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-sequence.html)'s increment call, hence making the sequence's value out of sync with the values in the column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the table before you initially insert data, it may be persisting from a previous run in which case (1, "bob") would already be in your table before you tried adding it again.

Comment: The issue is not during the initial add, but during normal operation afterwards. All the values with specified ids added correctly, but not the one with the `DEFAULT` id. Simulating this from the psql command line suggests that the inserting with ids is not updating the incrementor for the column.

Comment: I see, my mistake. I'm not entirely familiar enough with postgres to comment on how to keep track of the next id value that needs to be autogenerated

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT setval('users_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) from users));
```

The name of the sequence is auto generated and is always tablename_columnname_seq.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I try to insert into table:

```js
const Template = require("../models/templates");

async function addTemplate(user, body) {
  try {
    body.partner_id = user.partner_id;
    await Template.create(body);

    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error finding similar Template:", error);
    return null;
  }
}

module.exports = addTemplate;
```

The error:

```
Error finding similar Template: Error
    at Query.run (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:50:25)
    at C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:315:28
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PostgresQueryInterface.insert (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:308:21)
    at async model.save (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2490:35)
    at async template.create (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1362:12)
    at async addTemplate (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\query\addTemplate.js:9:20)
    at async C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\controllers\auth.js:629:24 {
  name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
  errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'id must be unique',
      type: 'unique violation',
      path: 'id',
      value: '4',
      origin: 'DB',
      instance: [template],
      validatorKey: 'not_unique',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ],
  parent: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "templates_pkey"
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:376:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:349:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:286:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 192,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '23505',
    detail: 'Key (id)=(4) already exists.',
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: 'public',
    table: 'templates',
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: 'templates_pkey',
    file: 'nbtinsert.c',
    line: '673',
    routine: '_bt_check_unique',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO "templates" ("id","partner_id","title","description","templates_html","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id","partner_id","title","description","templates_html","createdAt","updatedAt";',
    parameters: [
      1002,
      'Different Title',
      'Different Description',
      'Different HTML Content',
      '2024-01-20 06:05:48.934 +00:00',
      '2024-01-20 06:05:48.934 +00:00'
    ]
  },
  original: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "templates_pkey"
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rocks\Documents\Partner-Dashboard\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:376:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:349:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:286:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 192,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '23505',
    detail: 'Key (id)=(4) already exists.',
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: 'public',
    table: 'templates',
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: 'templates_pkey',
    file: 'nbtinsert.c',
    line: '673',
    routine: '_bt_check_unique',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO "templates" ("id","partner_id","title","description","templates_html","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id","partner_id","title","description","templates_html","createdAt","updatedAt";',
    parameters: [
      1002,
      'Different Title',
      'Different Description',
      'Different HTML Content',
      '2024-01-20 06:05:48.934 +00:00',
      '2024-01-20 06:05:48.934 +00:00'
    ]
  },
  fields: { id: '4' },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO "templates" ("id","partner_id","title","description","templates_html","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "id","partner_id","title","description","templates_html","createdAt","updatedAt";'
}
```

I found that the issue arises due to my seeder; I was seeding like:

```js
{ id=1,
    partner_id: 1001,
    title: "Product Showcase",
    description: "description 1",
},
{ id=2,
    partner_id: 1002,
    title: "Product Showcase",
    description: "description 1",
},
```

I just removed the `id`:

```js
{
    partner_id: 1001,
    title: "Product Showcase",
    description: "description 1",
},
{
    partner_id: 1002,
    title: "Product Showcase",
    description: "description 1",
},
```

Now it works.